# Failed to mount Windows share: Invalid argument

Tags: 14.04, networking, windows, samba

A very similar question has been asked before by `robazefa`, but no one answered it.
For the last month or so, my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS box has been been unable to open a couple of folders shared from external drives on a PC running Win 8.1 on a home network.

Through `Files` on the Unity desktop, I can browse the network, access the workgoup, access the Win 8.1 box, see and access its shares except the folders on its external drives.  They appear on the list and I could access them without a problem a couple of months ago, but now I get a dialogue box with `Unable to access location - failed to mount Windows share: Invalid argument` message, with only the option to click `OK`.

These folders are readily accessible now from other Win 7 and 8 PCs on the network, but the same `Invalid argument` error now appears on the only other Linux box on the network which runs Mint Cinnamon.

My question is which argument is in invalid and how can I validate it?

Comment: I had this start happening "suddenly" too.  I wonder which of the Linux updates broke things...

Comment: 1st attempt: You get this notice when Windows system's firewalling does not allow remote file accessing.

Comment: 2nd attempt: please tell us the filesystems these are on and check if your system supports it (exFat might need installing a driver).

Answer (score 14):

I resolved this by using the IP address instead of the server name.

Comment: and how did you obtain the IP address? ... How wuold you get it if you only know the server name?

Comment: @S.A.Ping the server name.

Comment: Walk over to the windows computer, open up Command Prompt, and type in `ipconfig`.

Comment: Bizarrely, this is still the answer on 22.04.3. What a total pile of crock.

Comment: Still the solution in 2024. `ping` did not work for me, but I could use `host <name>` to get the IP and then connect via the Gnome File Manager.

Answer (score 11):

This sounds like a regression. An [Ubuntu bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1442972) and [upstream bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747718) has already been made for it. It might be best to set yourself as "affected" and ask what information is needed. also clearly state that this is a regression. Regressions get fixed faster.

## [Workaround #1](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1824972)

You can try manually opening the share with nautilus (the file manager)

```
nautilus smb://ServernameOrIp
```

## Workaround #2

You can try [mounting it with `smbclient`](http://www.howtogeek.com/168115/mount-a-windows-shared-folder-on-linux-with-samba/). Example:

```
smbclient –L geekmini –U geek
```

Where geekmini is pc and geek is username.

Create mountpoint:

```
sudo mkdir /media/Video
```

Actually mounting the drive:

```
mount –t cifs –o username=geek,password=thepass //geekmini/root /media/Video
```

Answer (score 2):

edit `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

and  Disable SMBv1 and use SMBv2 works for me

like min protocol = SMB2

Comment: This didn't work on Ubuntu 22.

Answer (score 1):

My samba share has started to produce this same error after the group the shared directory had, and was shared to, has been erroneously deleted.

It got back to work OK after the situation with the disappeared group was resolved.

One could resolve it giving the share another group in the smb.conf file, but I just recreated it on the system level.

Hope this will help.

Comment: This is what worked for me. I had forgotten that I have created a group for samba users. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Same issues here -- although I found out that in win 8.1 introduced STORAGE SPACES into windows, allowing the clustering of hard drives into combined resources -- I have 8 drives of 4tb functioning as a single 32TB drive array.

I got mine to work by adding the option `-o vers=3.0` to my mount command and that solved my invalid argument error.

Hope that helps your situation.

Comment: Sorry, I should have posted earlier.  Nothing I tried worked when I first encountered the problem.  A couple of months ago, I found a workaround by accident.  Cleaning up, I unplugged all the peripherals from the PC.  Reconnecting them, I inadvertently plugged the old external HDD into a USB3 port.  Only later did I discover the invalid argument problem had gone away, but it no longer mattered because I had already moved all the files I wanted to other drives.

Answer (score 0):

Hade the same issue. For me the solution was to remove a line in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

Had a line:

```
client max protocol = NT1
```

Removed this line and now it worked.
It worked immediately, no restart or anything.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try restart windows... I don't now why but when I input (to map network disk) correct pass I have "Unable to access". After some many restart is it work all correctly :D